# How to dynamically process the java object?

Tags: java, object, design-patterns, dynamic, java-8

If we have a parent class Vehicle and its child classes as Bus, BiCycle, MotorBike.

At a certain point of time in a service class, I will be getting all the objects  like List  vehicles.

My Business logic should be like below,
A list of faulty vehicles will be received and for each vehicle type, a respective mechanic should be allocated.

If I receive a bicycle it should go to a bicycle mechanic or other vehicle and their respective mechanics.

It looked bad when I used to switch case and if else conditions.So I tried to use the Visitor pattern and Factory pattern, Factory pattern also will use either switch or if-else conditions to get the object dynamically and call the overridden method. Currently using the visitor pattern.

Kindly suggest some approach which would work better with this case.

Comment: sounds that you should define an additional interface has goToMechanic that will be implemented by bicyle and vehicles...

Comment: The Visitor pattern is fine. If there’s no actual objection against it from your side, this case can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a `sendToMechanic` abstract method in `Vehicle` class and override it with the appropriate definition in each of the child classes.

Comment: I don't want those methods to be in the sub-classes, be cause of the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest all three subclasses to implement the same interface (e.g. `repairable`) with a method like `allocateToMechanic. An interface is mostly describing "**what an object can do**" vs the abstract class which describes "**what an object is**".

Comment: Thanks for the response @stzoannos, I will try this out